# How to design a tree vertical menu with long dropdown？

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have two menu styles. One is [Tree frog vertical click](http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/tree_frog_vertical.html)  and the other is [Long Dropdowns](http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns).
Now, I wanna add the second menu style to the first one. So as to solve the long dropdown problem.
I tried, but failed. I think there some CSS style conflicted.
help me!

Comment: the Long Dropdowns hyperlink is http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that can be done without your code. However, did u try appending the second menu style with the first and then set transparency so that the second menu has its impact and doesnt affect the first menu style?